# Стили для подменю

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html5, css3

Проблема в том, что на сайте [написан на wordpress](http://http:/firenze.by) не получается задать чтобы пункт подменю был ниже самого основного меню.
Когда я задаю отступ сверху - оно просто скрывается. Как на скриншоте
[image: ссылка на скрин] 
А нужно его вывести точно под основным пунктом меню. Похожее реализовано на этом сайте [ccылка на сайт](http://enzzo.by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress тут ни при чем.

```
.sticky-wrapper .container.mobile-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это решило проблему:)

Comment: Не за что, заходите еще))